# git thinks some directories are files, can't sync them

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two directories that Git seems to be treating as files, and ignoring.

This is a collection of several folders, some of which come from Aptana, Eclipse, or PyCharm.  I found a couple of the folders that were under Git previously and had to remove the `.git` folder from them in order to get them to sync (they were showing as untracked and would not allow me to track them until the `.git` folder was removed).

How do I get those remaining folders to be recognized as such, and sync up to GitLab for me so I can finally have the entire monstrosity under source control?

Comment: What is git saying that makes you believe it thinks these directories are files?

Comment: have you tried adding the folders with something like `git add folder/*`?

Comment: Only thing I could come up with.  When I go to the web tool, it's showing these little icons that look like a cardboard box you might store files in (my guess was archive) and beside them it says something like @ 1c3b0d4172f which I assume is a commit number, but clicking the name of what should be a folder just reloads the page.  Tried a few GUI tools to see if they could shed some light on the problem, and two of them were displaying the same icon for individual files as they were for these particular beasts so I guessed it was treating them as files that were ignored for some reason. Ideas?

Comment: For reference, here's a screenshot of the display I'm talking about from gitlab.com.  http://postimg.org/image/pvtrwiyk5/

Comment: I would guess that those are not directories or files, but submodules...

Answer (score 3):

I'm still not entirely sure what the problem was, but here's how I fixed it.

1. Renamed the folders that weren't being uploaded/tracked properly
2. git add -u
3. git status
4. git add (anything shown in red on status)
5. git status (verify all are there)
6. git commit -m "Fixing garbage"
7. git push origin master

That took care of it.